# Unexpected results when using scikit-learn's SVM classification algorithm (RBF kernel)

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, scikit-learn

Using the example on this page 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_iris.html,
I created my own graphs using some normally distributed data with a standard deviation of 10 instead of the iris data.

My graph turned out to be like this:
[image]

Notice how the RBF kernel graph is very different from the the one from the example. The entire area is classified to be yellow except the red and blue bits. In other words there are too many support vectors. I have tried changing C and degree but they didn't help. The code I used to produce this graph is shown below.

Please note I need to use RBF kernel because polynomial kernels run significantly slower than RBF kernels.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from sklearn import svm, datasets

FP_SIZE = 50
STD = 10

def gen(fp):

  data = []
  target = []

  fp_count = len(fp)

  # generate rssi reading for monitors / fingerprint points
  # using scikit-learn data structure
  for i in range(0, fp_count):
    for j in range(0,FP_SIZE):
      target.append(i)
      data.append(np.around(np.random.normal(fp[i],STD)))

  data = np.array(data)
  target = np.array(target)

  return data, target

fp = [[-30,-70],[-58,-30],[-60,-60]]

data, target = gen(fp)

# import some data to play with
# iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features. We could
                      # avoid this ugly slicing by using a two-dim dataset
Y = target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

# we create an instance of SVM and fit out data. We do not scale our
# data since we want to plot the support vectors
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(X, Y)
rbf_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C).fit(X, Y)
poly_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C).fit(X, Y)
lin_svc = svm.LinearSVC(C=C).fit(X, Y)

# create a mesh to plot in
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - 1, X[:, 0].max() + 1
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - 1, X[:, 1].max() + 1
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h),
                     np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))

# title for the plots
titles = ['SVC with linear kernel',
          'SVC with RBF kernel',
          'SVC with polynomial (degree 3) kernel',
          'LinearSVC (linear kernel)']


for i, clf in enumerate((svc, rbf_svc, poly_svc, lin_svc)):
    # Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will asign a color to each
    # point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
    pl.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    Z = clf.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

    # Put the result into a color plot
    Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
    pl.contourf(xx, yy, Z, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)
    pl.axis('off')

    # Plot also the training points
    pl.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, cmap=pl.cm.Paired)

    pl.title(titles[i])

pl.show()
```

Comment: DId you use any other measure of correctness aside from what you get in the point.

Comment: For those that are also finding the poly kernel to be dreadfully slow, try scaling your data to the range [-1,1]. It sped mine up to the same speed as rbf. It mentions in the sci-kit api that the SVM works best on this range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DId you use any other measure of correctness aside from what you get in the point.

Usually SVMs need to be run using a grid search, specially if you have  an RBF, C only will take care of the regularization, which will do little if your data is not sparse to begin with.

You need to run a grid search over gamma and C, they have a really good example of that here:

http://scikit-learn.org/0.13/auto_examples/grid_search_digits.html#example-grid-search-digits-py

Also, their library already takes care of the cross validation.

Remember that those examples are good for the toy datasets, the moment you enter with a new dataset, there is no reason to believe is going to behave anything like the one in the example.